# Was the Men Behaving Badly theme tune in Fallout New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

My friend is insisting the Men Behaving Badly theme tune is in Fallout New Vegas (he says it plays in the background as you are walking through Freeside) but I'm sure he's wrong.

Is he?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what he could be confusing this with. The TV show theme was an original composition by [Alan Lisk](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0514075/), and none of it is credited in the [music list over at the Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_soundtrack).

Can you really see that odd, bouncy theme tune as backdrop to wasting Caesar's legions?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it was, one of the shops was playing it as you walk through Freeside, your friend's right!

Comment: Please, don't upvote inaccurate answers. Ryan, unless you can provide some evidence, I'm pretty sure @Gary's answer above, citing the credits from both the show and game demonstrate that while there might be a similar tune in both, the actual theme is not used.